# Decimal point alignment in LaTeX tabular environment but in math mode

Tags: tables, formatting

The `dcolumn` package works well for plain numbers but not if these are in math mode eg

```
\begin{tabular}{ld{1}l}
 \hline
  \textbf{Species}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Calculated}} & \textbf{Literature} \\ \hline
  2(3\textit{H})-furanone               & $-251.0$  &    \\
  2(5\textit{H})-furanone               & $-260.6$  &    \\
  5-methyl-2(3\textit{H})-furanone      & $-302.4$  &    \\
  5-methyl-2(5\textit{H})-furanone      & $-301.5$  &    \\
  2-oxiran-2-ylethenone                 & $ -72.3$  &    \\
\end{tabular}
```

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcafh,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}% provides $\celsius$  etc
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1} }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think `dcolumn` sets the columns in math mode anyway, so there's no need for the dollar signs.

Comment: Do you really want to get `$-251\cdot 0$` in the first row? It would be nice, if you make your example compilable and delete unneeded information. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi A centered dot has in some places been used as a decimal point, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#History

Comment: Thanks everbody; this was a simple case on my part of not RTFM for the DCOLUMN package

Answer (score 4):

From the third paragraph of the user guide of the [dcolumn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package:

> It should be noted that `dcolumn` *always uses math mode* for the digits as well as the [decimal] separator. [emphasis added]

In short, remove the `$` math mode initiator and terminator tokens from the second column of the table and you'll be in business.

By the way, you seem to be specifying the decimal column format as `d{1}`. I think it should be `d{4.1}`: you need to allow an extra digit's worth of space for the `-` (unary minus) symbol.

Comment: `{1}` is OK that's actually the original syntax where you just specify the number of digits to the right of the `.` (and the column is set flush right padded to that amount). `{4.1}` pads on both sides of `.` and then centres the result (which often looks better, but not always:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  - Thanks for this clarification. I guess I recommend `4.1` precisely because the numbers will then be centered in the column -- as well as aligned on the decimal marker.

Answer (score 3):

May I draw attention to the `siunitx`-package? One of my favourites. This would look like the following.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[journal=jpcafh,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Title}
\usepackage{siunitx} % provides \SI{}{\celsius} etc.
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {\cdot}}
            \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-3.1]l}\toprule
                \textbf{Species}  &  {\textbf{Calculated}} & \textbf{Literature} \\\midrule
                2(3\textit{H})-furanone           & -251.0 & \\
                2(5\textit{H})-furanone           & -260.6 & \\
                5-methyl-2(3\textit{H})-furanone  & -302.4 & \\
                5-methyl-2(5\textit{H})-furanone  & -301.5 & \\
                2-oxiran-2-ylethenone             &  -72.3 & \\\bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be worth mentioning explicitly that the output produced with the `dcolumn` package and a column specifier of `d{4.1}` will be *identical* to that of the `siunitx` package and a column specifier of `S[table-format=-3.1]`. I suppose that choosing one package or the other will depend importantly on whether one is already used to one package or the other.

Comment: @Mico Oh, yes, of course. It was meant as absolutely the same thing. Just other syntax.